# Prefixing ruby on rails table columns with table name to prevent ambiguous fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a few rails apps, some were production, some just for fun. Now I want to create an app that will be somewhat complex and there will be heavy usage of joins.

The current approach in rails for models is to have model.id, model.created_at and model.updated_at attributes autogenerated.

This is nice, but to avoid join hell, wouldn't it be better to have those fields prefixed with model name? Like so:

```
Company:
 - com_id
 - com_name
 - com_created_at
 - com_updated_at

Order:
 - ord_id
 - ord_com_id
 - ord_price_group
 - ord_created_at
 - ord_updated_at

Product:
 - pro_id
 - pro_code
 - pro_name
 - pro_price_def_cents
 - pro_price_pre_cents
 - pro_price_res_cents

OrderItem:
 - ori_id
 - ori_ord_id
 - ori_pro_id
 - ori_code
 - ori_name
 - ori_price_cents
 - ori_created_at
 - ori_updated_at
```

That way you could join all the models wihout naming problems:

```
OrderItem:
ori.ori_id: 19785,
ori.ord_id: 87450,
  ori.ord.com_id: 145,
    ori.ord.com.com_name: "Acme",
    ori.ord.com.com_created_at: 1970-01-01 00:00:00,
    ori.ord.com.com_updated_at: 1970-01-01 00:00:00,
  ori.ord.ord_price_group: "res",
  ori.ord.ord_created_at: 2015-12-31 14:56:01,
  ori.ord.ord_updated_at: 2016-01-31 01:00:00,
ori.ori_pro_id: 1780,
  ori.pro.pro_code: "pap-pla-80",
  ori.pro.pro_name: "Paper, plain, 80g",
  ori.pro.pro_price_def_cents: 16999,
  ori.pro.pro_price_pre_cents: 15999,
  ori.pro.pro_price_res_cents: 14999,
  ori.pro.pro_created_at: 1970-01-01 00:00:00,
  ori.pro.pro_updated_at: 1970-01-01 00:00:00,
ori.ori_code: nil,
ori.ori_name: nil,
ori.ori_price_cents: 14999,
ori.ori_updated_at: 2016-01-30 04:00:00,
ori.ori_updated_at: 2016-01-30 15:00:00
```

That way you can use all attributes "flattened" and never* have to worry about the attributes in case you just need to switch direction (you look at that specific OrderItem, or you want Orders including OrderItems and Company, or just want to know all Orders and OrderItems for a specific Company. Whatever way you join, the attributes would stay the same, so you could use the exact same partial for /order_item, /order -> items, /product -> orders -> items, /company -> orders -> items -> products etc.

The question is: Is this a good approach? Is it doable in Rails? How to solve the problem when we are tracking not our own Orders against our customers, but track orders between our customer (Company) and their customer (Company)? Can rails dynamically prefix attributes to prevent ambiguity? Or do you just have to always write a separate view for every possible scenario?

Comment: There are a few too many questions (count the question marks...).  Can this be reasonably narrowed down to just one?

Comment: That said: You can do this in Rails, but it will be a lot of work.  Rails makes your life easy if you do things its way, and hard if you don't.  Rails is deliberately opinionated.  For best results, follow the ActiveRecord convention for naming tables and columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off leaving the column names alone. In most cases you'd be using ActiveRecord, for example:

Company.join(:product).includes(:orders)

(Totes made up, probably doesn't work. At the least it needs the appropriate has_many/belongs_to etc. on the models)

And when you access various attributes things will just work. You don't need to do the prefixing, and you won't get join hell, because ActiveRecord will take care of it for you. If you look at the queries generated, there is join hell but that is ActiveRecord's problem.

tl;dr: don't prefix, Rails will handle it right if you let Rails handle it.

Comment: Note that if you want to reference columns that aren't unique, you will have to prefix, for example `Company.join(:product).includes(:orders).order('orders.updated_at')`